# Two textbox dates should not be greater to current date in javascript

Tags: javascript, html, asp.net, datetime

I have written a javascript condition for checking the date condition.

What my requirement is, I have two `textbox` in which I add the dates, And what I want to check is that.

My both the dates which are entered into the textbox should not be greater than Current date.

I have tried the below code but it is accepting the date which is greater than system date.

```
var todayDate = new Date();
   var todayMonth = todayDate.getMonth() + 1;
   var todayDay = todayDate.getDate();
   var todayYear = todayDate.getFullYear();

 var todayDateText = todayMonth + "/" + todayDay + "/" + todayYear;
    var Dt1 = document.getElementById('txtFormDt').value;
    var Dt2 = document.getElementById('txtToDt').value;
  if (todayDateText > Dt1) 
    {
        alert("System Date Should be grater than From Date");
    }
     if (todayDateText > Dt2) {
         alert("System Date Should be grater than To Date");
    }

       if (Dt2 < Dt1) {
           alert("To Date Should be grater than From Date");
           return false;
       }
       return true;
  }
```

Comment: Convert the dates into epoch and then compare. String format of dates should not be compared.

Comment: @PulkitMittal: I am unaware of epoch, can u help me with that.

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date

new Date().getTime() would give you a value, which is number of milliseconds since Jan 1, 1970. Similarly, you would need to parse the text in the input boxes to convert it into similar epoch time and then only you can compare two dates.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can compare Date objects directly using the `<`, `>`, `>=` and `<=` operators but not `==` or `===` since Dates are also Objects. However, make sure you correctly parse the values from the inputs, e.g.

```js
function checkDate(el) {
  var form = el.form;
  var now = new Date();
  var date = parseMDY(form.startDate.value);
  form.parsedDate.value = date;

  if (!date || isNaN(+date)) {
    form.result.value = "Invalid date";
  } else {
    form.result.value = date < now;
  }
}

// Parse string in m/d/y format
// Returns invalid date if month or day out of range
function parseMDY(s) {
  var b = s.split(/\D/);
  var d = new Date(b[2], --b[0], b[1]);
  return d && d.getMonth() == b[0]? d : new Date(NaN);
}
```

```html
<form id="f0">
  Insert date (m/d/y)<input type="text" name="startDate">
  <input type="button" onclick="console.log(checkDate(this));" value="Check date">
  <br>
  Input date: <input name="parsedDate" readonly size="50">
  <br>
  Before today?<input name="result">
</form>
```

Comment: how can I implement this in my  code ??. I added ur code in my new page and when I add the before date it was giving date and condition as `true`